# Creating an algorithm for a roulette bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, bots

I was wondering if there's any way that I can make a bot that can play roulette (casino game in case you're wondering) while still making a profit?

Say we have a simpler version of a roulette game where the following features count:

- Number range is from 0 to 14
- Red is 1 - 7
- Black is 8 - 14
- Green (the rare one) is 0
- You can only bet on either color and any amount you want (as long as you have  the amount)
- A number from the range is picked at random each round.
- Colors red and black will grant you twice the amount you bet if you win
- Green will grant you 15 times the amount since it's 1/15 chance to get the number.

I'm using NodeJS to create my bot, and so far without any luck. This is of course only for practice and it would be pointless to use on a casino anyways since if you're winning too much, you're most likely to get thrown out.

**Edit (13.10.2019):**

I realize now, 4 years later, that this was a kind of silly question since no, there isn't any way to create a bot that could win every game of roulette. *Because that's how the game is designed...*

For those stumbling upon this question today, I apologize for the silly question. I was a naive kid wanting to win some CS:GO skins by creating a bot, not realizing that if creating a bot that can win every time, gambling in roulette probably wouldn't be a thing.

For those with the same question, see @Draco18s answer. He explains it pretty well why there is *no* way to win every time in roulette.

Comment: Sure, it's probably doable.

Comment: The binomial distribution governs the mathematics behind this. You will discover that you cannot make money on average in the long run.  The best you can hope for is a short-term deviation based on luck, but the more "trials" (or spins) you play, the more your expectation will converge toward the long-term expectation (which is a slight loss, not profit). Basically the 2 greens ("0" and "00") are what slowly eat you up.

Comment: If there was a way to beat the game casinos wouldn't let you play it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

Here's the thing.  If you bet Red or Black, winning double, your odds of winning are 7/15, or 46%.  This means that on average, you will lose 8% of your bet with every spin of the wheel.  Betting Green will break even.  Betting on any other number, assuming the same 15x payout as betting Green, you still only break even (typically numerical bets ignore 0 and 00, so you'd only get 14x of your bet, not 15x).

There is no strategy that will lead to making a profit unless the randomness of the chosen winning number has a bias.  All true roulette wheels in real casinos develop a slight bias, but they are often checked and maintained on a regular schedule, and the casino tracks all bets being made and will locate a player who has found the bias before that player has made any significant winnings.

http://www.casinoinsider.com/roulette/gonzalo-garcia-pelayo-roulette-made-millions/

Comment: Agreed.  Smart money is on the slot machines.

Comment: Slot machines pay out at between 89% and 96%, depending on their type, location, and minimum bet.

Comment: 89% is like a B+, right? and 96% is a solid A.  I'll take those odds!

Comment: That means for every dollar you spend, you win 96 cents.  I'm not sure that counts as winning. ;)

Comment: By the way, all the averages assume that you play an infinite number of times.  For any finite number of attempts there is a non-zero *probability* that you do better than the average.  But also a non-zero probability that you *do worse* as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no strategy that will allow you to win in the long-term.